# Can I access Graph API with AzureAD IDToken

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have JavaScript website which access Azure AD protected WebAPI with IDToken.
Is there any way to call Graph API (to get groups) from WebAPI which is already authenticated with IDToken.

I use msal in my JS to get access to the WebAPI. I pass scope to the WebAPI, I tried to add another scope to Graph but then I had an error.
I tried to call Graph with Authorization key in the header and Bearer  as the value from my WebAPI but this didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an ID token wrong.
The ID token should not be used for authorization in a back-end.

Your front-end needs to acquire an access token for your back-end. Your back-end can then exchange that access token for an access token for Graph API.

Or your front-end can call Graph API. 
You cannot specify both scopes when acquiring a token because a token is only valid for one API. 
You can however make two separate calls to acquire the tokens.

Comment: I have make the change you mentioned. After I acquired a Graph API access token I have an error 'Insufficient privileges to complete the operation' it looks like my Web API hasn't got access to read user data. I need to mention that I have a multitenant architecture so user which I want to get the data doesn't exists in the same AD as my WebAPI. To get the Graph token I use: ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder I pass WebApi registered app client Id and secret